# c++ firebase segmentation fault, linux, at std::string::assign Cannot access memory at address 0xf

Tags: c++, linux, firebase

Problem with using firebase C++ SDK on linux, for some reason it throws segmentation fault from inside the library.

I have next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "firebase/app.h"
#include "firebase/analytics.h"
extern "C" int common_main(int argc, const char* argv[]);
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    return common_main(argc, argv);
}
    int common_main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    namespace analytics = ::firebase::analytics;
    ::firebase::App* app;
    ::firebase::AppOptions appOptions;
    appOptions.set_app_id("project-540NUMBERNUMBER67RR"); // changed
    appOptions.set_api_key("CoDeCoDeCoDeCoDeOcDeCoDeCoDeCoDeCoDeCod"); // changed
    app = ::firebase::App::Create(appOptions);
    analytics::Initialize(*app);
    return 0;
}
```

And next stacktrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
std::string::assign (this=this@entry=0x6170d0, __str=<error reading     variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xf>)
at /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-5.3.0/work/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:693
693     /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-5.3.0/work/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  std::string::assign (this=this@entry=0x6170d0, __str=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xf>)
    at /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-5.3.0/work/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:693
#1  0x0000000000402175 in std::string::operator= (__str=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xf>, this=0x6170d0)
    at third_party/crosstool/v18/stable/toolchain/x86_64-grtev4-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.9.x-google/bits/basic_string.h:555
#2  firebase::AppOptions::operator= (this=0x6170c8) at blaze-out/gcc-4.X.Y-crosstool-v18-hybrid-grtev4-k8-opt/genfiles/firebase/app/client/cpp/include/firebase/app.h:23
#3  firebase::App::Create (options=..., name=0x402bb5 "default") at firebase/app/client/cpp/src/app_stub.cc:43
#4  0x00000000004013ae in common_main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdea8) at /home/ivan.sidarau/source/firebase_t/firebaseTest/main.cpp:29
#5  0x0000000000401306 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdea8) at /home/ivan.sidarau/source/firebase_t/firebaseTest/main.cpp:14
```

on x86_64 platform. With Firebase C++ SDK version 1.0.

So problem probably somewhere in this code / otherwise ABI / or SDK.

Anyone met something like that before?

Answer (score 0):

For now is not possible to use C++ SDK with on linux platform.
Google Firebase C++ SDK use JNI/Java SDK internals on Android or iOS. It is not available on linux.